# HorizontalPager not taking full width while scrolling in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a `ComposeView` in an xml and loading a `HorizontalViewPager` in that view. My expected behaviour of that pager is when I scroll the items of that pager it should not be inside the bound of the padding of the parent layout but take the edge to edge scrolling instead.
Here is the current look:
[image]

But I want something like this:
[image]

This is how I am getting the viewpager:

```
HorizontalPager(
                count = promotionalBanners.size,
                state = pagerState,
                itemSpacing = 8.dp,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(end = 16.dp)
            ) {

                Card(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(172.dp)
                ) {
                    NetworkImage(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .aspectRatio(1.8f)
                            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
                            .clickable {
                                context.openUrl(
                                    promotionalBanners[it].redirectUrl,
                                    navController
                                )
                            },
                        imageUrl = promotionalBanners[it].bannerUrl,
                        contentDescription = promotionalBanners[it].redirectUrl,
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
                    )
                }
            }
```

Can any one suggest me how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself. Here is how I have solved it. In the xml where the composeview is places I have added this:

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_promotional_banner"
        android:layout_marginStart="-16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rec_partners"/>
```

The -16dp did the trick here, it managed to disobey the parent layout padding, after that the simple below code placed the viewpager in position:

```
HorizontalPager(
                count = promotionalBanners.size,
                state = pagerState,
                itemSpacing = 8.dp,
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate your `conentPadding` based on your item size.

```
val horizontalPadding = 16.dp
val itemWidth = 340.dp
val screenWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = horizontalPadding, end = (screenWidth - itemWidth + horizontalPadding).dp)
```

Try this solution.